# Pandas: Exclude items from an array column if that item is in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as the follwoing below:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'USER':[1,2,3,1,1,2],
                  'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD', 'LD', 'LD', 'TR', 'SVM']})
    
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'USER': [1,2,3,4,5],
                        'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE': ['SJDR1', 'LD', 'LD', 'TR', 'SVM']})
```

I do `merge` and `groupby` in order to create a list in `ANTENNA_ID`, as shown below:

```
merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='USER', right_on='USER')

grouped = merged.groupby('USER').agg({'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE': min, 'ANTENNA_ID':list}).reset_index()
grouped
```

How I can exclude items in `ANTENNA_ID` if this item is in `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE`? An output example:

```
USER | PRESUMED_RESIDENCE |   ANTENNA_ID
 1   |       SJDR1        | [LD, TR]
 2   |        LD          | [SVM]
 3   |        LD          | []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea with list comprehension:

```
grouped['ANTENNA_ID'] = [[z for z in x if z != y] 
                         for x,y in zip(grouped['ANTENNA_ID'], 
                                        grouped['PRESUMED_RESIDENCE'])]

print (grouped)
   USER PRESUMED_RESIDENCE ANTENNA_ID
0     1              SJDR1   [LD, TR]
1     2                 LD      [SVM]
2     3                 LD         []
```

Another idea with custom lambda function, I guess slowier if large `DataFrame`:

```
f = lambda x: [z for z in x['ANTENNA_ID'] if z != x['PRESUMED_RESIDENCE']]
grouped['ANTENNA_ID'] = grouped.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`List.remove()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove) in [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

**Note:** This will make change inplace.

```
In [4695]: grouped.apply(lambda x: x['ANTENNA_ID'].remove(x['PRESUMED_RESIDENCE']) if x['PRESUMED_RESIDENCE'] in x['ANTENNA_ID'] else x['ANTENNA_ID'], 1)

In [4696]: grouped
Out[4696]: 
   USER PRESUMED_RESIDENCE ANTENNA_ID
0     1              SJDR1   [LD, TR]
1     2                 LD      [SVM]
2     3                 LD         []
```